# How to set the facecolors of Poly3DCollection from points in the 2D projection?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, projection

### Question

Start with a set of 2D points where each point lies directly below exactly one 3D path object in a Poly3DCollection. How can you assign the `facecolor` parameter for the path object to match the color of the point below it?

I probably need to determine if a point lies in the 2D projection of a Poly3DCollection object onto the xy-plane. Then I can assign the color value of that point to the appropriate object in the collection.

### Background

Given an image of a Rubiks Cube, my program identifies a specific point in the middle of each of the colored squares. I save these points as a 2D array and assign the correct color to each point (see below). My goal is to reconstruct a 3D model of the cube using these points.

Matplotlib has a [method](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/path_api.html) `mpl.Path.contains_point(...)` that checks to see if a point lies within the bounds of a given path object. This only works for 2D paths. I used this method to recreate a 2D model of the cube.

[image: Rubiks cube with colored points]
[image: 2D recreation of the cube]

### Current Progress

In addition to the 2D pictures above, I made the 3D model of the cube (or at least the visible faces) but the colors are not specified. I can even plot the points and Poly3DCollection on the same subplot. The image on the right was hard-coded to show that the colors from each point should line up with each path object.

[image: Bottom-up view]
[image: Projecting the colors]

### Code

This is the relevant portion of my code for reproducibility.

```
faces = np.array([[[285, 140,  89],[265, 171, 122],[229, 170,  92],[249, 139,  59]],[[249, 139,  59],[229, 170,  92],[193, 169,  62],[213, 138,  29]],[[213, 138,  29],[193, 169,  62],[157, 168,  32],[176, 137,   0]],[[265, 171, 122],[245, 203, 155],[209, 202, 125],[229, 170,  92]],[[229, 170,  92],[209, 202, 125],[173, 201,  95],[193, 169,  62]],[[193, 169,  62],[173, 201,  95],[137, 200,  65],[157, 168,  32]],[[245, 203, 155],[225, 234, 188],[189, 233, 158],[209, 202, 125]],[[209, 202, 125],[189, 233, 158],[153, 232, 128],[173, 201,  95]],[[173, 201,  95],[153, 232, 128],[117, 231,  98],[137, 200,  65]]])
xs = np.array([221, 137, 187, 146, 242, 210, 172, 155, 236, 262, 119, 104, 104, 139, 121, 216, 238, 118, 259, 144, 162,  92, 207, 180, 224, 185, 198])
ys = np.array([ 66, 101,  58,  49,  94,  90,  83, 145, 126, 121,  66, 167, 104, 173, 135, 207, 182, 199, 158, 221, 189, 136, 185, 161, 160, 213, 121])
clrs = ['white','orange','green','white','white','green','white','orange','green','white','orange','red','blue','blue','white','blue','orange','red','green','blue','orange','red','orange','green','yellow','white','white']

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

cbs = Poly3DCollection(faces, edgecolor='k', zorder=1, alpha=0.7)
ax.add_collection3d(cbs)

ax.scatter(xs, ys, ([0]*len(xs)), s=20, color=clrs, edgecolor='k', alpha=1.0, zorder=5)

ax.set_xlim(-50, 300)   
ax.set_ylim(-50, 300)   
ax.set_zlim(-50, 300)   
ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
    
plt.show()
```